# Move Log files mid-production in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, log-files

Team I need your help. We have a client running Exchange 2010 and we need to move and point the Log files to a external drive mid production. This will not be a long term solution , just a temporary one until the proper changes are made.  Is this possible? Can someone point me to a best practice?

Comment: By "mid-production" do you mean, while Exchange is running?

Comment: What about referring to this similar case: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9e0ef348-35be-46af-8d98-77b8dd5a16fa/questions-about-moving-log-file-location-in-exchange-2010?forum=exchange2010  See the prerequisites here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2010/dd351168(v=exchg.141)#prerequisites

Comment: https://dailysysadmin.com/KB/Article/1838/change-the-log-file-location-in-exchange-2010/

Comment: I found a related link based on your question: http://www.buchatech.com/2010/10/move-exchange-2007-stores-logs-to-a-different-disk/